# Why does Vim's U command work differently when lines are changed vs deleted?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to understand the `U` command in Vim. My understanding is that it undoes all changes that affect only the most recently changed line. However, if I start with the following file:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

`jxx` navigates down and deletes two characters:

```
abc
f
ghi
```

`kgU2j` sets the entire document to uppercase:

```
ABC
F
GHI
```

Now, `U` gives this result:

```
ABC
def
GHI
```

If I had used `kd2j` to delete the entire document instead of changing its case, `U` would have no effect. I'm wondering why `d` is treated as a command that affects multiple lines, but `gU` is seemingly ignored.

Is there an intuitive way to understand this behavior, or is this just an odd edge case of Vim?

Comment: Perhaps this description from [vi](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/vi.html) is more useful than that of `:help U`: "Restore the current line to its state immediately before the most recent time that it became the current line."

Answer (score 0):

To understand this behaviour I decided to dig into the source code and the things I found:

- After change that touches single line we [store that line number in variable](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/09f7723d5a8694889350b13e3f6b4a9c3ed4c41f/src/undo.c#L3470). It's not affected when we touch more than line at once.

In your case, you removed one letter from second line. **Current line** (and the **state** before the change) was updated. When you deleted next character, you did it in the already stored line, so **current line** nor **state** were updated. Next change touched 3 lines - no updates. `U` restored **current line** to saved **state**. Notice that `gUG` on the last line would touch only it, so that change updates **current line** and **state** under the hood.

- After changes to document structure (adding/removing lines), [that variable is cleared](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/09f7723d5a8694889350b13e3f6b4a9c3ed4c41f/src/ops.c#L844)

This can move **current line** up (deleting) or down (adding). It's much easier to clear it instead of handling logic of moving it and that's my guess why it's done such way.

Notice that deleting part of line (e.g. with d$) will update **current line** and **state** as expected. Opening line with `o` and type some text (**current line** is that line, **state** is empty line) works too. However when you press enter during typing (so affect more than one line), **current line** is cleared.